# How to check if a List is empty and fill with NaN before merging into an array

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am scanning through a text document line by line and looking for certain values. When I find the value, I append it to a list for that item.

```
I set up empty lists to start:
    shot=[]
    Veast=[]
    Vnorth=[]
```

When I finish the scan I merge all the lists into an np.array.

```
data=np.array([[shot],[Veast],[Vnorth])
```

I then reshape and stack it and turn it into a DataFrame:

```
##Sort 'Shot' as index
a=np.array([shot]).reshape(-1,1)
#Stack the rest of the array against 'shot' 
for i in range(1,len(data)):
    i = data[i].reshape(-1,1)
    a=np.hstack((a,i)) 
#Convert to DF
global df

df=pd.DataFrame(data=a,columns=["shot","V0e","V0n"])
```

This works when all the targets of my search are present, all the list are of the same length and shape.

However, some files may have a missing search target so the list is empty and the hstack fails.

```
...7227694.1, 7227700.2])]
 [list([])]
 [list([])]
 [list([426827.2, 426826.5,...
```

I can make a very complex set of 'if' loops or pre-checks to work around it but I wonder if there is a simpler options.

1. Can I check for an empty list before I make the array and fill it with NaN to the same length as the other lists?
2. Can I check for an empty list and exclude those lists from the np.array construction and subsequent hstack and DataFrame build?

Any suggestions on how to do either, or something else would be greatly appreciated.

The 'full' code for this section is as follows:

```
#merge individual lists
data=np.array([[shot],[Veast],[Vnorth],[S011east],[S011north],[S012east],[S012north],[C1n1east],[C1n1north]
       ,[C1n2east],[C1n2north],[T11east],[T11north],[T12east],[T12north]
       ,[R1east],[R1north],[R97east],[R97north]])


##Sort 'Shot' as index
a=np.array([shot]).reshape(-1,1)
#Stack the rest of the array against 'shot' 
for i in range(1,len(data)):
    i = data[i].reshape(-1,1)
    a=np.hstack((a,i)) 
#Convert to DF
global df

df=pd.DataFrame(data=a,columns=["shot","V0e","V0n","S0_Pe","S0_Pn","S0_Se","S0_Sn","CMP_Pe","CMP_Pn"
                                ,"CMP_Se","CMP_Sn","T_Pe","T_Pn","T_Se","T_Sn"
                                ,"R1e","R1n","R97e","R97n"])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went with option 1 above, find and fill empty arrays. I have added the following before the #merge individual arrays.

```
if not Veast:
    for line in shot:
        Veast.append(np.NaN)
        Vnorth.append(np.NaN)
```